# Finding the source MAC address in Router Advertisements

Tags: network, mac-address, networking

What is the source MAC address in the Router Advertisement packets received on the interface eth1?

-i have ran tcpdump -i eth1 and tcpdump -n -i eth0 icmp6

-ifconfig eth1 and tried using the HWaddr to answer the question but it was 
still wrong.

-Tried using arp -i eth1 command also. no dice

Not looking for an answer just looking for some guidance. Not quite sure what the question is asking

Comment: Welcome.  Your question reads like there's a diagram which should go with it, could you give us a little more information so we can help?

Comment: @jonathanjo There are no diagrams, which makes it harder.  I'm under the impression that it is asking find out where eht1 is receiving traffic.  It just pops me onto a linux machine and asks me to figure out the question.  

I can't use wireshark also. This machine is pretty much locked down

Comment: Unfortunately, all "_education, certification, or homework_" questions are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: @RonMaupin where should i go to ask these questions then?

Comment: There are literally hundreds of network education sites on the Internet. Unfortunately, this is not one of them. This site is for supporting professionally managed networks in a business environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have the right filters and are nearly there:

To look for IPv6 router advertisments on eth1, use tcmpdump and filter on 1) correct interface, 2) ICMP version 6.  You'll need -e to show MAC addresses.

```
tcpdump -nvve -i eth1 icmp6
```

Comment: 23:04:28.137802 02:42:ac:13:00:04 > 33:33:00:00:00:01, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 110: (flowlabel 0xeb6cf, hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload leng
th: 56) fe80::42:acff:fe13:4 > ff02::1: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, router advertisement, length 56
hop limit 64, Flags [none], pref medium, router lifetime 12s, reachable time 0s, retrans time 0s
  prefix info option (3), length 32 (4): 2080:34fa:1234::/64, Flags [onlink, auto], valid time 86400s, pref. time 14400s
    0x0000:  40c0 0001 5180 0000 3840 0000 0000 2080
    0x0010:  34fa 1234 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

Comment: I used 02:42:ac:13:00:04, and 33:33:00:00:00:01 for the answers and it still didn't take.

Comment: "Didn't take" in what?  From your comment, 02:42:ac:13:00:04 is definitely the MAC address of something sending router advertisements on the interface you're running traceroute on.

Comment: I used 02:42:ac:13:00:04 as the answer.  THis is a question from a lab.  It said incorrect, but i know i'm right cause you can confirm it to.  Thank you!